# Spark Dataset equivalent for scala's "collect" taking a partial function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Regular scala collections have a nifty `collect` method which lets me do a `filter-map` operation in one pass using a partial function. Is there an equivalent operation on spark `Dataset`s?

---

I'd like it for two reasons:

- syntactic simplicity
- it reduces `filter-map` style operations to a single pass (although in spark I am guessing there are optimizations which spot these things for you)

---

Here is an example to show what I mean. Suppose I have a sequence of options and I want to extract and double just the defined integers (those in a `Some`):

```
val input = Seq(Some(3), None, Some(-1), None, Some(4), Some(5))
```

**Method 1 - `collect`**

```
input.collect {
  case Some(value) => value * 2
} 
// List(6, -2, 8, 10)
```

The `collect` makes this quite neat syntactically and does one pass.

**Method 2 - `filter-map`**

```
input.filter(_.isDefined).map(_.get * 2)
```

I can carry this kind of pattern over to spark because datasets and data frames have analogous methods.

But I don't like this so much because `isDefined` and `get` seem like code smells to me. There's an implicit assumption that map is receiving only `Some`s. The compiler can't verify this. In a bigger example, that assumption would be harder for a developer to spot and the developer might swap the filter and map around for example without getting a syntax error.

**Method 3 - `fold*` operations**

```
input.foldRight[List[Int]](Nil) {
  case (nextOpt, acc) => nextOpt match {
    case Some(next) => next*2 :: acc
    case None => acc
  }
}
```

I haven't used spark enough to know if fold has an equivalent so this might be a bit tangential.

Anyway, the pattern match, the fold boiler plate and the rebuilding of the list all get jumbled together and it's hard to read.

---

So overall I find the `collect` syntax the nicest and I'm hoping spark has something like this.

Comment: The `collect` method defined over `RDD`s and `Dataset`s is used to materialize the data in the driver program.

Despite not having something akin to the Collections API `collect` method, your intuition is right: since both operations are evaluated lazily, the engine has the opportunity to optimize the operations and chain them so that they are performed with maximum locality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `collect` method defined over `RDD`s and `Dataset`s is used to materialize the data in the driver program.

Despite not having something akin to the Collections API `collect` method, your intuition is right: since both operations are evaluated lazily, the engine has the opportunity to optimize the operations and chain them so that they are performed with maximum locality.

For the use case you mentioned in particular I would suggest you take `flatMap` in consideration, which works on both `RDD`s and `Dataset`s:

```
// Assumes the usual spark-shell environment
// sc: SparkContext, spark: SparkSession
val collection = Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(collection)
val dataset = spark.createDataset(rdd)

// Both operations will yield `Array(2, 4, 6)`
rdd.flatMap(_.map(_ * 2)).collect
dataset.flatMap(_.map(_ * 2)).collect

// You can also express the operation in terms of a for-comprehension
(for (option <- rdd; n <- option) yield n * 2).collect
(for (option <- dataset; n <- option) yield n * 2).collect

// The same approach is valid for traditional collections as well
collection.flatMap(_.map(_ * 2))
for (option <- collection; n <- option) yield n * 2
```

**EDIT**

As correctly pointed out in another question, `RDD`s actually have the `collect` method that transforms an `RDD` by applying a partial function just like it happens in normal collections. As the [Spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect():Array[T]) points out, however, "this method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory."

Comment: Thanks for the answer @stefanobaghino! That seems to leave me with just method 2 so far which I'm not keen on. Even though there is no collect, is there a more idiomatic and concise way to solve my example for a spark dataset?

Comment: For the case in your answer in particular, `flatMap` will do. :-) `val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2), None, Some(3))); rdd.flatMap(_.map(_ * 2)).collect` will output `Array(2, 4, 6)`. You can also use a for-comprehension. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer! I forgot about the `for`.

Comment: I think the collect with PartialFunction doesn't have this problem... the warning is in the other method (collect without arguments).

Answer (score 4):

<strike>The answers here are incorrect, at least with the current of Spark.</strike>

RDDs do in fact have a collect method that takes a partial function and applies a filter & map to the data. This is completely different from the parameterless .collect() method. See the Spark source code RDD.scala @ line 955:

```
/**
 * Return an RDD that contains all matching values by applying `f`.
 */
def collect[U: ClassTag](f: PartialFunction[T, U]): RDD[U] = withScope {
  val cleanF = sc.clean(f)
  filter(cleanF.isDefinedAt).map(cleanF)
}
```

This does not materialize the data from the RDD, as opposed to the parameterless .collect() method in RDD.scala @ line 923:

```
/**
 * Return an array that contains all of the elements in this RDD.
 */
def collect(): Array[T] = withScope {
  val results = sc.runJob(this, (iter: Iterator[T]) => iter.toArray)
  Array.concat(results: _*)
}
```

In the documentation, notice how the

```
def collect[U](f: PartialFunction[T, U]): RDD[U]
```

method does **not** have a warning associated with it about the data being loaded into the driver's memory:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@collect[U](f:PartialFunction[T,U])(implicitevidence$29:scala.reflect.ClassTag[U]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[U]

It's very confusing for Spark to have these overloaded methods doing completely different things.

---

*edit*: My mistake! I misread the question, we're talking about DataSets not RDDs. Still, the accepted answer says that

> "the Spark documentation points out, however, "this method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory."

Which is incorrect! The data is not loaded into the driver's memory when calling the partial function version of .collect() - only when calling the parameterless version. Calling .collect(partial_function) should have about the same performance as calling .filter() and .map() sequentially, as shown in the source code above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question was about data sets though, not rdd's. One of the other answers mentions how you can turn a data set into an rdd then call collect.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake! I'll edit the answer, it still might be useful for some to see the difference between .collect() and .collect(pf).

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of completeness:

The RDD API *does* have such a method, so it's always an option to convert a given Dataset / DataFrame to RDD, perform the `collect` operation and convert back, e.g.:

```
val dataset = Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2)).toDS()
val dsResult = dataset.rdd.collect { case Some(i) => i * 2 }.toDS()
```

**However, this will probably perform worse** than using a map and filter on the Dataset (for the reason explained in @stefanobaghino's answer).

As for DataFrames, this particular example (using `Option`) is somewhat misleading, as the conversion into a DataFrame actually does the "flatenning" of Options into their values (or `null` for `None`), so the equivalent expression would be:

```
val dataframe = Seq(Some(1), None, Some(2)).toDF("opt")
dataframe.withColumn("opt", $"opt".multiply(2)).filter(not(isnull($"opt")))
```

Which, I think, suffers less from your concerns of having the map operation "assume" anything about its input.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to extend stefanobaghino's answer by including an example of a  `for` comprehension with a case class as many use cases for this will probably involve case classes.

Also options are monads which makes the accepted answer very simple in this case as the `for` neatly drops out the `None` values, but that approach wouldn't extend to non-monads like case classes:

```
case class A(b: Boolean, i: Int, d: Double)

val collection = Seq(A(true, 3), A(false, 10), A(true, -1))
val rdd = ...
val dataset = ...

// Select out and double all the 'i' values where 'b' is true:
for {
  A(b, i, _) <- dataset
  if b
} yield i * 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always create your own extension method:

```
implicit class DatasetOps[T](ds: Dataset[T]) {

  def collectt[U](pf: PartialFunction[T, U])(implicit enc: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U] = {
    ds.flatMap(pf.lift(_))
  }
}
```

such that:

```
// val ds = Dataset(1, 2, 3)
ds.collectt { case x if x % 2 == 1 => x * 3 }
// Dataset(3, 9)
```

Note that I've unfortunately not been able to name it `collect` (thus the awful suffix `t`) as the signature would otherwise (I think) clash with the existing `Dataset#collect` method that transforms a `Dataset` into an `Array`.